# node js get object array object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi everyone good day,

how can I get the value of this object that is returning from this

```
  Post.find().lean() 

  .exec((err, post) => {

    console.log(post);

    req.post = JSON.stringify(post);

    console.log(req.post);
  });
```

the first console log returns this

```
 [ { photo: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

the second console log returns this

```
 [{"photo":[{"_id":"5d7dd20185251921882e2ba1","data":"...","contentType":"image/jpeg"}]}]
```

now what i want to get is the contentType and data.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After stringify do `post = JSON.parse(post)` ,then you can access `post.data` and `post.contentType`

Comment: It just returns to this [ { photo: [ [Object] ] } ] after parsing

Comment: you can access the value by looping the photo